# Using Polymer's vulcanize tool without an index.html file

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, polymer, web-component

Background: I am using Polymer web components in my app but I would like to reduce the number of HTML imports because it is affecting performance now. I am using Jade templates inside Sails.js. Sails.js doesn't generate an index.html for my app on build but rather generates HTML from my Jade templates and serves them on request. According to the documentation, [vulcanize](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize) will concatenate all the HTML imports in a source HTML file into a build HTML file.

Question: 
Is it possible to vulcanize the generated HTML before serving it to the client? Sails.js uses Express so I assume that this would involve creating some Express middleware (such as [vulcanize-middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/package/vulcanize-middleware)?).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library which lets you concatenate a bunch of web components into one file for express.

[Vulcanize-Middleware](https://github.com/k2wanko/vulcanize-middleware)